# Pod affinity settings is not working properly in my deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, affinity

I try to deploy 2 replicas on **k3s** - each one to a different node. According to documentation, it should be pretty easy. However, I must be doing some silly mistake I am not able to find. When I apply the deploy file, both of my pods are running the same node (*node1*). In case I switch that node off, these pods start on another 2 nodes (*node2*, *node3*). When I start the *node1* back and redeploy the app, it runs again on the same node1.
If somebody can advise please, what I have wrong in my configuration, I would be really grateful.
(I run fresh new k3s on 3 servers with the same HW configuration)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tbd-node-js-runner
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tbd-node-js-runner
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tbd-node-js-runner
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: app
                operator: In
                values:
                - tbd-node-js-runner
            topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/hostname
      containers:
        - name: tbd-node-js-runner
          image: tabidoo/nodejs-runner:latest
          ports:
          - containerPort: 
          env:
          - name: CONNECTION_STRING
            value: "..."
            ...
          imagePullPolicy: Always
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
```

Comment: can you add `kubectl get nodes --show-labels` output to the question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- It is due to incorrect topologyKey , It should be 'kubernetes.io/hostname' not 'topology.kubernetes.io/hostname' .
- So it would be as following :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tbd-node-js-runner
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tbd-node-js-runner
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tbd-node-js-runner
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: app
                operator: In
                values:
                - tbd-node-js-runner
            topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
      containers:
        - name: tbd-node-js-runner
          image: tabidoo/nodejs-runner:latest
```

Comment: Yes. That's it.
Thank you! Thank you very much. I do not believe I missed that. I read it so many times.

Comment: @MichalCumpelik you can accept the answer if in fully satisfied you

Comment: Yes, I did not find it before. Now, it is accepted, I hope. Thanks for notification.